# How to set the vs project's PostBuildEvent to download from FTP on Linux?

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, monodevelop, post-build-event

I need to compile a VS project under Linux using MonoDevelop. It worked successfully except the command at the project.csproj file like this:

```
<PostBuildEvent>echo get pub/xxx.exe | ftp -A xxx.com</PostBuildEvent>
```

It can't run on Linux.I know it is possible to use a sh-script to establish the ftp connect, but I really want to know how to run it just by setting the project's postBuildEvent. The code I tried to connect FTP server is this:

```
echo anonymous |ftp -p xxx.com
```

This couldn't login to the server.I could use it at normal Linux's command line.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK it is so easy.Just needs 7zSD.sfx and a config.txt, then

```
cat 7zSD.sfx config.txt yourproject'spackage.7z > yourproject.exe
```